# How to get data from window to another with WPF and MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I build a small task app, in my first window I have a list of my task, when I click Create button it open new windows with textbox to write a title and content for the new task.

My need is to get the title and the content written in the second windows in my first windows to add this new task in my list.

My code look like this :

MainViewModel :

```
    public class MainViewModel : Notifyer
{

    ObservableCollection<Task> mTasks;
    public ObservableCollection<Task> Tasks { get { return this.mTasks; } set { this.mTasks = value; Notify("Tasks"); } }


    private ICommand m_ButtonAddCommand;
    public ICommand ButtonAddCommand { get { return m_ButtonAddCommand; } set { m_ButtonAddCommand = value; } }


    private ICommand m_ButtonDeleteCommand;
    public ICommand ButtonDeleteCommand { get { return m_ButtonDeleteCommand; } set { m_ButtonDeleteCommand = value; } }


    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ButtonAddCommand = new CommandHandler(() => add_task(), true);
        ButtonDeleteCommand = new CommandHandler(() => delete_task(), true);

        mTasks = new ObservableCollection<Task>();
        mTasks.Add(new Task("title1", "content1", true));
        mTasks.Add(new Task("title2", "content2", false));
    }

    private void add_task()
    {
        NewTaskWindow w = new NewTaskWindow();
        w.Show();
        //how to get my content ???
    }

    private void delete_task()
    {

    }
}
```

and NewTaskViewModel :

```
    public class NewTaskViewModel : Notifyer
{
    private ICommand m_ButtonAddCommand;
    public ICommand ButtonAddCommand { get { return m_ButtonAddCommand; } set { m_ButtonAddCommand = value; } }

    private String title;
    public String Title { get { return this.title; } set { this.title = value; Notify("Title"); } }

    private String content;
    public String Content { get { return this.content; } set { this.content = value; Notify("Content"); } }

    public NewTaskViewModel()
    {
        ButtonAddCommand = new CommandHandler(() => add_task(), true);
    }

    private void add_task()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Title);
        Console.WriteLine(Content);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the model into the window without any injection. It is not necessary.

```
WindowModel windowModel = new WindowModel();
Window window = new Window(windowModel);
```

*Inside Window Class*

```
public Window(windowModel)
{
   DataContext = windowModel;
}
```

Dont forget to remove the references for model injection for this window.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create windows inside your viewodel, but with dependency injection. To solve your problem try this:

```
private void add_task()
{
  NewTaskWindow w = new NewTaskWindow();
  var taskViewModel = ( NewTaskViewModel )w.DataContext;
  var title = taskViewModel.Title;
  var content = taskViewModel.Content;
  w.Show();
}
```

Comment: seem to works, also, how can I close my TaskWindow when I click on a button from ViewModel ?

Comment: NewTaskViewModel, on add_task method

Comment: Store the window(s) in a field so you can access it from an other method

Comment: Storing the window(s) in a field (I assume you mean ViewModel class field) is a violation of the MVVM pattern. Inter ViewModel communication usually happens via a message service (also called EventAggregator or MessageAggregator)